# UITableView not correctly animating cells that are re-ordered off screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController for my Data Source.

When I reorder a cell and it moves up or down to a position that is on screen or just slightly off screen, the cell moves to it's new position with an animation.

However, when the row is moving to a new position which is well off screen, it just gets moved without any animation.

Ideally, I would like the row in those cases to animate down or up until it's off screen.  Is there any way to achieve this without implementing a custom method?

The case I am using here is the .move in the following delegate call:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    case .move:
        tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `UITableViewRowAnimation.fade` or something like that.

Comment: yes, that makes no difference at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614987-moverow), `UIKit` will animate move operations for all cells, however it is happening so fast that it's not very visual.

So, you can actually get the desired effect by two `move(at:,to:)` calls with `performBatchUpdates` as follows:

```
guard indexPath != newIndexPath, let paths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else { return }
if paths.contains(newIndexPath!) {
    tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
} else {
    tableView.performBatchUpdates({
        let index = indexPath < newIndexPath ? (paths.count - 1) : 2
        tableView.moveRow(at:indexPath!, to: paths[index])
        tableView.moveRow(at: paths[index], to: newIndexPath!)
    })
}
```

Note that to achieve upward scrolling animation, you have to set the `paths` index to be 2 as the midpoint for moving upward.

Comment: very good solution but unfortunately it only works for rows moving down, not for rows moving up.  using paths.first! as the midpoint for rows moving up causes some strange animations.  also, occasionally even the rows moving down stop in the intermediate position and do not move all the way down.

Comment: @alionthego See my updated answer for upward scrolling. For the other issue, this code can be adapted to animate with multiple intermediary move operations. If the two rows are very far apart, the issue occurs. :)